# How to write and read from process with Ruby and IO.popen?

Tags: ruby, popen

I wrote this, but it didn`t work...

```
output = IO.popen("irb", "r+") do |pipe|
  pipe.gets
  pipe.puts "10**6"
  pipe.gets
  pipe.puts "quit"
end
```

I rewrite so

```
IO.popen("irb", "w+") do |pipe|
  3.times {puts pipe.gets} # startup noise
  pipe.puts "10**6\n"
  puts pipe.gets # I expect " => 1000000"
  pipe.puts "quit" # I expect exit from irb
end
```

but It didn`t work too

Answer (score 5):

**In general the above example will hang because the pipe is still open for writing**, and the command you called (the ruby interpreter) expects further commands / data.

The other answer sends `__END__` to ruby -- this works here, but this trick will of course not work with any other programs you might call via `popen`.

**When you use `popen` you need to close the pipe with `IO#close_write`.**

```
 IO.popen("ruby", "r+") do |pipe|
   pipe.puts "puts 10**6"

   pipe.close_write    # make sure to close stdin for the program you call

   pipe.gets
 end
```

See: [Ruby 3.1 popen*](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html)

---

**In more Detail:**

In Ruby, `IO.popen`, `IO.popen2`, `IO.popen2e`, and `IO.popen3` are methods used for working with subprocesses, and they differ in how they handle input, output, and error streams. Here's an explanation of the differences and when to use each:

1. **`IO.popen`**:

   - `IO.popen` is a versatile method that allows you to create a subprocess and interact with its standard input and output.
   - It returns an array containing the subprocess's standard input, standard output, and a thread representing the subprocess.
   - It's suitable for basic subprocess interaction when you need to send data to the process and capture its output.
   - *Example:*

     ```rb
     stdin, stdout, thr = IO.popen('some_command')
     ```
2. **`IO.popen2`**:

   - `IO.popen2` creates a subprocess with separate pipes for standard input and output.
   - It returns an array containing the subprocess's standard input and output streams.
   - It's useful when you want to send data to the process and capture its output separately.
   - *Example:*

     ```rb
     stdin, stdout = IO.popen2('some_command')
     ```
3. **`IO.popen2e`**:

   - `IO.popen2e` is similar to `IO.popen2`, but it combines the standard output and standard error streams into a single stream.
   - It returns an array containing the subprocess's standard input and combined standard output/error streams.
   - This is useful when you want to capture both output and error messages together.
   - *Example:*

     ```rb
     stdin, stdout_err = IO.popen2e('some_command')
     ```
4. **`IO.popen3`**:

   - `IO.popen3` creates a subprocess with separate pipes for standard input, standard output, and standard error.
   - It returns an array containing the subprocess's standard input, standard output, standard error, and a thread representing the subprocess.
   - It's suitable for scenarios where you need to interact with the process, capture its output, and handle potential error messages separately.
   - *Example:*

     ```rb
     stdin, stdout, stderr, thr = IO.popen3('some_command')
     ```

When to use each version depends on your specific requirements:

- Use `IO.popen` when you need to interact with a subprocess's input and output and don't require separate handling of error messages.
- Use `IO.popen2` when you want to capture the standard output separately from the standard input and need to send data to the process.
- Use `IO.popen2e` when you want to capture both standard output and standard error together in a single stream.
- Use `IO.popen3` when you need separate pipes for standard input, standard output, and standard error, and you want to interact with the subprocess and capture both output and error messages separately.

Comment: What if you don't want to close the write pipe? I'm in a situation where I want to send a message to a process and read back the results, then send another and another etc. I tried `pipe.flush`, `pipe.sync = true` all to no avail

Comment: Actually nevermind, `pipe.flush` was the right thing to do, I was missing a flush after the other process wrote its output.

Answer (score 4):

Either do

```
IO.popen("ruby", "r+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts "puts 10**6"
  pipe.puts "__END__"
  pipe.gets
end
```

or do

```
IO.popen("irb", "r+") do |pipe|
  pipe.puts "\n"
  3.times {pipe.gets} # startup noise
  pipe.puts "puts 10**6\n"
  pipe.gets # prompt
  pipe.gets
end
```

Comment: I rewrite so <pre>IO.popen("irb", "r+") do |pipe|
  3.times {puts pipe.gets} # startup noise
  pipe.puts "10**6\n"
  puts pipe.gets # I expect " => 1000000"
  pipe.puts "quit" # I expect exit from irb
end </pre> but It didn`t work too

Comment: Try with `2.times` instead of `3.times`. I got a `puts` in my `.irbrc`.

Comment: Only output: Switch to inspect mode.

Comment: Let's just leave it at 'irb is not to be played with'? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I found open3, it`s OK for me

Comment: see my answer. you need to use `IO#close_write` on the pipe.